# Design Patents- What exactly are these patents on?

Tags: design-patent, description, usd674720, usd652759, usd670191

What exactly is the patent FOR on the following items?  I see no notice of color, finish, size, materials, assembly method, etc. 
D652759 (Pendant-Slit Pupil), 
D683254 (Pendant-Round Pupil), 
D682730 (Pendant Oblong Pupil), 
D653151 (Plug-Slit Pupil), 
D670191 (Plug-Round Pupil), 
D674719 (Plug-Oblong Pupil), 
D662005 (French-Slit Pupil), 
D671439 (French-Round Pupil), 
D665693 (French-Oblong Pupil), 
D674720 (Post-Oblong Pupil), 
D672681 (Post-Slit Pupil)

Answer (score 2):

Usually when we think of a patent we are thinking of a **utility patent**. They cover the function of something.

These are all **design patents**. Design patents only cover the ornamental aspects of a item of manufacture. Ornamental can mean shape, texture, finish, color, printed material, patterns, reflectivity, translucency, etc. In many cases, as in the ones of these I have looked at, only the shape and a decorative pattern are shown and claimed. There are some design patents that say "in one embodiment the back is shiny" or "the back and front are in contrasting colors".

What something is made of and how it is made are complete non-issues in design patents. Just what it looks like is at issue.